# slide animate floating action button android

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design, floating-action-button

I've a view with a FAB and a navigation drawer opens up on the right side when the FAB is clicked.
I want the FAB to move to left side of the screen when the drawer opens and when the drawer closes the FAB should move back to its original position.

How can I implement this with a translation effect for the fAB? I need help.

Comment: Do you have coordinator layout as your root view?

Comment: Yes, I've changed it to a coordinator Layout.